# Unable to access all functinalities in seaparate .aspx page having same code as Masterpage without asigning to it

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, dom-events, master-pages

I made a separate .aspx page, for website(not assigned to master-page). On menu-bar I created 10 hyperlinks & for those hyperlinks,another 4(sub)hyperlinks & made `Function:menuover` in Javascript, to height-light (sub)hyperlinks and I want to display those (sub)hyperlinks  on mouseover.

This function is displaying on every page; but on that separate .aspx page it displays only 3 out of 4 (sub)hyperlinks. I copied same code `Function:menuover` of Masterpage for that separate .aspx page.

So, can any one help me to I access same code for separate .aspx page?

Comment: you need to provide the code, markup and (if applicable) the specific error. what you posted above it useless.

Comment: my guess, is that if you are referring to the links by ID in the javascript the problem is the client side id's rendered by webforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a usercontrol (.ascx) file and move the code there.

Then add a property to the .ascx.cs file:

```
public bool ShowABCLink { get; set; }

protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.ShowABCLink) this.ABCLink.Visible = false;
}
```

Now include the usercontrol in your .aspx pages (use drag-n-drop in the designed to automatically handle the uc1 prefix registration etc.):

```
<uc1:Navigation runat="server" ShowABCLink="true" />
```

On the other page specify `false`. There are other, very similar ways of doing this but this should be the easiest for you.